# Resize screen for Dead touch zone

Tags: touchscreen

I have Star N7189 (5.5") with the lower zone of touch screen dead

[image: Dead zone]

The menu and back buttons don't work,but the physical home button works.

I tried to press hard on the edges of the screen, I tried to apply a twist from the short sides as if it were nothing but a wet towel. I did the hard reset but it did not work.

Sometimes pressing dead area, the phone takes it as menu button

As well as replacing the screen what other methods can I try? Is there any app, launcher or trick to resize the screen usable only to the working area?

P.S. a few hours after leaving it in airplane mode suddenly the touch had this problem but I do not remember if I inadvertently placed something heavy in that area of ​​the cell.

Comment: You *might* be able to achieve this by editing the source of a custom ROM to your needs and recompiling it, but if you don't already know how to build your own custom ROM, I wouldn't recommending it.

Comment: For Android 11+: [Decrease the screen size (not resolution) on Android 11 (`wm overscan` is deprecated)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230374/44325).

Comment: For newer android users, sadly `overscan` doesn't work on android 12+. 
I had water ingress and bottom edge was randomly triggering touches. Changing the screen resolution helped me. It is easy enough with adb, not very elegant but works. `adb shell wm size 1080x1920`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51807840

Answer (score 40):

*A partial but possibly helpful answer, but* ***would not work on Android 11 and above.***

---

**Note:**

- My solution is tested on Stock Android 4.4.2 and Stock CyanogenOS 12 (5.0), and should work for Android 4.3 and above (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18601415/4720957)).
- I've mentioned wherever root access is required.

The issue in [this existing answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/112720/2) is that it reduces the screen output from both top and bottom in my devices while I need to reduce only from the bottom. To do so I used the following  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500611/android-how-to-use-adb-shell-wm-to-simulate-other-devices#comment49936824_19922688) as the ground to work on:

> The bottom 20% of my Nexus 4 doesn't work. I use: `wm overscan 0,0,0,210` to have android WM not draw anything in that area so that I can operate all the drawn areas fully again.. –  Thrustmaster

##Instructions:

1. [Enable USB-debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/67353/96277) in your phone.
2. Install [ADB tools](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/96277) in your PC, connect your device into it, and make sure that device is getting detected in `adb devices`.
3. We need to know the resolution and the display density of the device. In the terminal/cmd enter `adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo` to show display related info. The output could look like:

   ```
    mBaseDisplayInfo=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 480 x 854, real 480 x 854, largest app 480 x 854, smallest app 480 x 854, 64.29 fps, rotation 0, density 240, 240.0 x 240.0 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
   ```

The relevant info in my case is:

- real 1080x1920
- density 480

4. 
5. The most useful commands to be used are:

- `wm overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]`
- `wm density [reset|DENSITY]`

  My default launcher screen without tweaks looked like:

  [image: IMG: Default launcher screen without tweaks]

2. To reduce the screen output at bottom issue the command:

   ```
       adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,100
   ```

   Note the I used further reduction by upto `0,0,0,300` and the output was like this:

   ```
   [![enter image description here][3]][4]
   ```

   Tweak the value to your desired needs.
3. You may need to correct the density since the display could look [odd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFXyF.jpg). My device's default display density is 480 dpi, so I tweaked it this way:

   ```
       adb shell wm density 440
   ```

   and the resultant screen was like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjMd6.jpg). An [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCl7p.png) under tweaked resolution.
4. Note that you can use `adb shell wm density reset` and `adb shell wm overscan reset` to revert back to default density and resolution respectively.
5. Now that "dead touch zone" has been taken care of it's time to use virtual/soft keys (only if you need it).

   1. [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) has it already covered in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57274/96277). Otherwise, you can use [Gravitybox LP](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox) (for Lollipop users) or [Gravitybox KK](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) (for Kitkat users). It is an Xposed module, and **require root access** and [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) installed.

      Install, activate and launch Gravitybox → **Navigation bar tweaks** → **Enable Navigation bar** → do a reboot, and soft-keys aka Navigation bar would be found enabled.
   2. Custom ROM like Cyanogenmod and some stock ROMs has the option to enable soft-keys(buttons) under **Settings**. You can use that option since it doesn't require any root access.
   3. After some further tweaks the final screen of my Android 5.0 looked like:

      [image: IMG: After some further tweaks the final screen of my Android 5.0 looked like]

---

<sub>Note that the aforesaid solution probably wouldn't be relevant for the OP, but it is written considering the objective of the [bounty](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/57267/revisions) (offered by [barro32](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/114471/barro32)).</sub>
<sub>Next big update possibly would be for Android 4.2.</sub>

Comment: The adb commands for overscan worked perfectly on my Essential PH-1 and the solution was very simple, without root or apps. I can use my phone again. Thank you.

Comment: worked for me Nokia 7.1 broken screen thank you you saved my life

Comment: Does it work after a system re-boot?

Comment: @MaciekŁoziński For the Android versions I tested upon (mentioned at the top), yes, it did work post reboot.

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the "LEDs" of the dead part?

Comment: @viyps I have no information on that. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for leading me to this answer which worked for me https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230374/decrease-the-screen-size-not-resolution-on-android-11-wm-overscan-is-deprec

Answer (score 3):

If your device is rooted, you might want to take a look at [Button Savior (Root)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Button-Savior-Root/com.smart.swkey) – if not, at [Button Savior Non Root](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Button-Savior-Non-Root/com.smart.swkey.nonroot). Or at [Virtual Button Bar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Virtual-Button-Bar/opotech.virtualbuttonbar):

[image: Button Saviour] [image: Virtual Button Bar]
<sup>*Button Saviour* and *Virtual Button Bar* (source: Google Play; click for larger images)</sup>

What do all the three have in common? As the screenshots show, they enable virtual softkeys at places where you want them. So you can avoid the "dead areas", and still have them present.

Admitted, this does not resize the screen; but at least fixes the problem with the buttons.

Comment: Good part of the problem is not solved so, in fact all applications that require that area of the screen, including the keyboard, remain unusable ;(

Comment: I was aware of that – but thought better a partly solution than none. As for the keyboard, there are some keyboard apps which allow you "free positioning". I just stumbled upon such a while ago, but do not remember which one it was.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
**Requires root and android 4.3+!!!**

This app can change your resolution and also add virtual buttons.
You will need to **change the height** about **1.5cm smaller**.(can't see it very good on your picture so check it before applying!) If you have any problems with the app, check the app's description or post a comment below.

Hope my answer helps you!

Download link for app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nomone.resolution_changer

Comment: The issue with "am/wm display-size" on which the said app relies is that 1.5cm will be reduced from both top and bottom, shrinking the screen usage to way too less. Correct me if I'm wrong but I noticed this behavior on my device.

Answer (score 1):

[Firelords answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113782/191822)  works for Android Versions above 4.2.

**For Versions up to (including) Android 4.2** the command to use is `am`. After enabling USB-Debugging and installing ADB tools, the procedure is:

1. Detect the current display resolution: `adb shell dumpsys window` (or better to directly filter the output for the resolution: `adb shell dumpsys window | grep cur= |tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 4|cut -d "=" -f 2)` - [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904970/4988103))
2. Change the resolution to e.g. 540x700 `adb shell am display-size 540x700`. (Can be reset with `adb shell am display-size reset`)
3. If neccessary to change the display density then check the current density with `adb shell dumpsys display` (or to get a short output: `adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo`)
4. Change the density to e.g. 230: `adb shell am display-density 230` (Can be reset with `adb shell am display-density reset`).

If neccessary to enable soft keys/on-screen buttons, this can be done by adding the line `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0` to the file `/system/build.prop` (required root permissons). If this line already exists in the build.prop, on-screen buttons can be enabled by setting the value to 0 or disabled by setting it to 1. As far as I know, this works from Android 4.0 on.