# Resizing the screen size

Tags: screen, touchscreen

Bottom area of my phone is not responding to touches. I was wondering if there's anyway I can only use a part of my screen.

I haven't been able to find any good solutions, other than for floating virtual buttons.

The phone in question is a Nexus 4, can be rooted or flashed with a custom ROM if required. I feel comfortable with compiling a ROM if there's an easy modification that allows this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this one, https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113782