# Replacing L-style soft buttons with KitKat-style soft buttons?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop

I'd like to upgrade my Nexus 5 from CM11 (based on Android 4.4.2) to CM12 (based on Android 5), but I can't stand the new ultra-minimalist soft button icons of Android L.

I find myself constantly forgetting which is which (why is Home a circle?) and just don't like their visual appearance.

**Is there any way to replace the Android L soft button icon set with the Android K soft button icon set?**

[image: Kitkat] [image: Lollipop]

Comment: I thought GravityBox could help but it didn't. May be you can find this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/57274/96277) useful, if not satisfactory to the goal.

Comment: There is this [SoftkeyZ Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.janis605.softkeyz) which claims to change those soft-key icons, or try this [article](http://lg-g3.wonderhowto.com/how-to/add-more-soft-key-styles-your-lg-g3-no-root-required-0156718/) which mentions XDA threads having soft-keys collections.