# Disable touchscreen area (root available)

Tags: root-access, touchscreen, broken-screen

My rooted Xperia Z1 on Android 5.1 has a broken touchscreen area in the upper half of the screen.

I was able to partly solve the problem by following this SO question:
[Resize screen for Dead touch zone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone)

My problem is: The broken area constantly sends touch events. By that, I am not able to input any touch events myself.

### How can I filter any touch events in the upper half of my screen?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `wm size (WIDTH)x(HEIGHT)`
the difference between `size` and `overscan` is that any input outside the screen area will be ignored if you use `size` to change the display resolution

first you have to know the resolution and the display density of the device. In the terminal/cmd enter `adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo` to show display related info. 
in my case it's

- real 1080x1920
- density 480

the equivalence for `wm overscan 0,0,a,b` is `wm size (WIDTH-a)x(HEIGHT-b)`. In my case `wm overscan 0,0,30,0` --> `wm size 1050x1920`