# Disable part of a touchscreen from taking phantom touches

Tags: adb, touchscreen

I have a 10.Or G android Oreo device

- Resolution: 1080x1920
- Density: 480

This question follows up from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123290/disable-touchscreen-area-root-available)

I'm having problem with lots of ghost touches in the very top 5 mm bar of the screen where touches will register almost 20 times in a minute. Doing the overscan doesnt help at all, because touches will still register, so I am looking to resize my screen with:

```
adb shell wm size 1080*1820
```

I dont know what to do from here because I'm receiving error:

```
Error: bad size 1080*1820
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use x not * in the command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `overscan` subcommand instead of `size` for achieving your objective.
The syntax is `adb shell wm overscan left,top,right,bottom`, where **left**, **top**, **right** and **bottom** are the coordinates relative to the actual edges of the screen.
So, in your case, you should write `adb shell wm overscan 0,100,0,0`, to get a resolution of 1080×1820, as you have mentioned above.

**Explanation:** This will set your device's screen bounds to 0px from the left, 100 px from the top, 0 px from the right and 0 px from the bottom. See this image:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, the command is working, but this command reduces my screen size evenly from the top and bottom halves, after applying 1080x1820, the screen moved down by 50px from top and it moved 50px from bottom. since the area that causes the phantom touches is the top most part, is there a way to just restrict the top 50px , and save my screen real estate?

Comment: That is quite normal. The screen size will get distributed evenly across the bounds of the screen. See my edits for the solution.

Comment: I have used the exact overscan command you have mentioned (you can see the attached link in question) but the overscan did not stop the phone from taking touches, that's why i was inclined to stop the top 100px from taking any touches. Again, help will be appreciated.  Please refer to the question link given in my question.

Comment: Here is the picture of what I've encountered https://imgur.com/a/csiw0h8 notice how the top bar takes touches.. if you'll provide with a solution/any solution, I will be very thankful

Comment: You can try increasing the **top** co-ordinate of the command. You can write `adb shell wm overscan 0,200,0,0` and check whether it's working or not. Because, the Phantom touches may be extending to more than 100px from the top.

Comment: Or, you can use the command `adb shell wm size 1080x1720`. As you can see, that by using this technique, you need to sacrifice 100px from the bottom of the screen as well !!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error `Error: bad size 1080*1820` because it should be `x` and not `*` which is also mentioned when typing `adb shell wm`:

```
  size [reset|WxH|WdpxHdp] [-d DISPLAY_ID]
    Return or override display size.
    width and height in pixels unless suffixed with 'dp'.
```

So, the correct command is `adb shell wm size 1080x1820` which won't result in any error. You can find out more using `adb shell wm` which returns:

```
Window manager (window) commands:
  help
      Print this help text.
  size [reset|WxH|WdpxHdp] [-d DISPLAY_ID]
    Return or override display size.
    width and height in pixels unless suffixed with 'dp'.
  density [reset|DENSITY] [-d DISPLAY_ID]
    Return or override display density.
  folded-area [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]
    Return or override folded area.
  overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM] [-d DISPLAY ID]
    Set overscan area for display.
  scaling [off|auto] [-d DISPLAY_ID]
    Set display scaling mode.
  dismiss-keyguard
    Dismiss the keyguard, prompting user for auth if necessary.
  set-user-rotation [free|lock] [-d DISPLAY_ID] [rotation]
    Set user rotation mode and user rotation.
  set-fix-to-user-rotation [-d DISPLAY_ID] [enabled|disabled]
    Enable or disable rotating display for app requested orientation.
  tracing (start | stop)
    Start or stop window tracing.
```

You will most likely have to combine this with the [other answer mentioned here about `overscan`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210448/221364) to find a fix for your use case.