# resize screen for dead touch zone (using adb command)

Tags: touch

My Oneplus One fell recently, and I can't use the bottom 2-3cm of the touchscreen.

I found this question here: [Resize screen for Dead touch zone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone)

I tried the option using `adb`.
I only used the command: `adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,400`

But I get this screen:
[image]

Apparently it uses the overscan double. Once above the soft-keys, and once above them.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: What happens when you use a launcher other than the built-in one (Trebuchet)?

Comment: I have the same problem using Nova Launcher.

But when an app is opened, it's normal, so it's only on the homescreen.

Comment: Interesting... +1

Comment: I have the same problem.