# How to resize the screen on Android 4.2.2 (adb shell wm overscan doesn't work)

Tags: adb, 4.2-jelly-bean, screen

I was following this tutorial in order to resize my screen (or "deactivate" a small part from the bottom of it): https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113782/191822

As describes above I tried tried it with ADB. I'm using Android 4.2.2, which is probably the reason why the following command doesn't work:

```
adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,100
/system/bin/sh: wm: not found
```

Replacing *wm* by *am* didn't work either:

```
adb shell am overscan 0,0,0,100
...
...
Error: Unknown command: overscan
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish that with Android 4.2.2

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04

**EDIT:** ok, I've come so far to notice that the command I have to use might be something like:

```
adb shell am display-size
```

e.g. (from 540x960 to 540x700)

```
adb shell am display-size 540x700
```

However, this will resize the screen on the top and the bottom. I couldn't find a way to only remove a part of the screen from the bottom withouth changing the screen position on the top.