# Resize Android screen resolution at top and bottom because of dead zones

Tags: notification-bar, screen-resolution

I need to resize and move my Android screen in order to be able to use the drop-down notification bar since the top and bottom parts of the screen are dead.

I was able to work with bottom buttons (back, home, recents) after using:

```
wm overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]
wm density [reset|DENSITY]
```

as described in [this existing question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone). This worked for the bottom dead zone, but not for the top. I'm still not able to use the notification bar by swiping down from the top. Is there any way to resize the area of effect of the notif. bar to achieve this or anything similar?

My screen resolution is 720x1280 - 320 dpi. It's a Sony Xperia Z3C.

Comment: Sorry for closing your question prematurely. I'd expect the same technique to work for both, so I've edited to make it clear what part of the problem you still need help with. Could you add the exact commands you've used on your phone?

Comment: @DanHulme I shrinked the screen by 15 px at the bottom only because when I tried to do it with the top part it didn't sort any effect. I still wasn't able to use the notification bar.