# Create a dead zone on a screen using adb to fix phantom touch

Tags: screen, stock-android, android-device-manager

Many a times a very specific area of a screens starts to show phantom touches. In this case a very simple tweak to just remove the touch sensitivity from this very specific area could fix the problem. Even an xposed module would do.

How could I achieve this? I'm using CM 13 and I know how to use adb. Please don't give me the same 'just buy a new screen bs' . Those screens aren't cheap. Somtimes the screen can cost half the price of the phone.

Thousands of people have this problem. If we can achieve this we could very well save a lot of money.

Comment: Don't spam please! You have already asked 2 similar questions in less than 1 one day.

Answer (score 1):

I also got that problem. I tried the command `wm overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]` (from [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone)). That didn't fix the problem but helped a lot.