# Extend usable area of the screen

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, touchscreen, touch

I have an old unrooted android phone with the bottom zones touch not working. I followed this [Post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/57267/322447) to resize my screen to avoid the dead zones. But the menu launcher icon is near the middle of the usable screen and also the menu area is reduced to almost half *(see the images below)*. Is it possible to remove the gap between **menu/menu-launcher and navigation buttons** so that I can get more usable screen?

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u37Y6.jpg)

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djPaX.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the density too?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the gap was still there.