# Scale entire display down a couple pixels due to replacement screen?

Tags: samsung, screen

I'm not familiar with Android Stack Exchange so apologies in advance if I am asking this in the wrong place or word something wrong.

Recently I replaced a damaged screen with a new one on my Samsung A8 2018. I noticed pretty quickly that the screen digitizer seems to go over the display itself by a couple pixels on both the top and the bottom. This is pretty annoying as it cuts off some of the information I need to read that is located there (such as notification bar).

I think that the solution to this would be to scale the screen down vertically just by a couple pixels on either end but do not know how to do this. I have tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone) , but the scaling starts underneath the notification bar which does not help me. The phone is not rooted (but I do plan to root it in the near future so any solutions that involve rooting are still helpful) and I do use adb for super basic things once in a while.

Does anyone know of any apps or of an adb command that could scale down the entire length of the display and leaving the empty areas of the screen black?

Answer (score 0):

There's a command called `wm` window manager, which can basically set the screen density, size and overlay. Now, to make sure if you have `wm` binary on your device, try opening a shell(android terminal or an adb shell) and then try typing `wm`. If it shows a bunch of helpful stuffs, then good news, you have that and probably can use it. Now, in your case, since things go out of screen limits, it's probably the screen size that needs to be customized here. Now before jumping into the main command, try seeing the screen ratio of your device first. Type `wm size` and it'll show your screen resolution. Now, for eg, if it says 800x480. You need to shrink the size a bit and adjust until you find the correct ratio, for eg to decrease, type in `wm size 790x450`, to resize the window resolution.

Now, just before applying all of these, if you're planning to do this from your Android terminal, you'll need root privillege, since for the moment you have no root privillege, adb shell could most definitely work. Hopefully this helps (: If you don't happen to have `wm` binary by any chance, maybe installing busybox would be a better idea.

***This post might be helpful as well***

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500611/android-how-to-use-adb-shell-wm-to-simulate-other-devices