# Decrease the screen size (not resolution) on Android 11 (`wm overscan` is deprecated)

Tags: screen, android-11

I recently bought a Pixel 4a and being used to a way smaller phones before (4.7 inches), it's gigantic for me. I'm trying to find a way to decrease the usable space of the screen (from the top) and hide the camera cutout.

I found out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-vHE7t8_qg), but the option is only available on Samsung (and other brands). Then I found out [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone) and the `wm overscan` ADB command and just as it looked like I found a solution, it turned out Google deprecated the overscan command in Android 11.

I tried also Nacho Notch and other "notch-hiding" software, but they only "blacken" the notification bar and don't actually reduce the screen size.

Any ideas what I can do to actually achieve this on Android 11?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue with my Google Pixel 4a. Fortunately even though overscan is deprecated, setting `size` still works. The downside is that the screen is centered instead of being aligned to the bottom of the screen.

Open a root shell on your phone, then run:

```
wm size # to get your current phone display size
wm size 1080x1800 # slightly reduce the display size
```

You can also use `wm size reset` to reset the display size.

Edit: you can also use [Screen Shift](https://www.f-droid.org/en/packages/com.sagar.screenshift2/) to edit the screen resolution. (Overscan won't work.)