# Can one change the screen resolution on Google Pixel 6?

Tags: screen-resolution, android-12, google-pixel-6

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12. Can I change the screen resolution? I can't find the option in the settings.

Comment: Have you tried using adb? `adb shell wm size WxH`

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Decrease the screen size (not resolution) on Android 11 (`wm overscan` is deprecated)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230374/44325)

Comment: [This](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6111557?hl=en) will show you where to do it in Settings:

Comment: @CodyB. thanks I don't see a mention of the resolution Or is it the display size?