# Grant shell user permissions to apps

Tags: adb, permissions

Using adb, one has a lot of additional permissions, that apps running locally on the phone have.

Specifically, I am interested in the `wm size` command.

Is there a good way to allow apps access to those permissions?

The only way I know of, is to use `adb tcpip`, so that apps can connect to the adb server running on the phone. But afaik, thata wouldn't survive a reboot.

Comment: Based on your [prior question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246480/3573) I don't think it is possible without root (or at least having the user go through the hack) as `adb` is an obvious security liability. Sadly I think your desired behavior for your hardware project is only available via Custom ROM.

Comment: Yeah, those questions are related. I am running into different issues where I have a couple workarounds, but most of them require root or other not-so-cool things, which work for me, when I am using the keyboard attachment, but I am trying to make this a bit more accessible to other users. It's not a showstopper, but its just more comfort and stuff.