# Resize screen to avoid dead zone - problem with adb

Tags: adb, screen, broken-screen

Asking a question because it seems that nobody has got the same problem after resizing it's screen using adb because of a dead zone on my phone over the status bar. I've basically followed the steps explained in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115484/resize-screen-to-display-only-on-working-part-of-semi-functional-touchscreen), but after doing the overscan command, some apps seem to double the overscan for some reason, as you can see in the 2 pictures attached (one with a top overscan of 20, the other with an overscan of 50, to show how the status bar gets lower, but the space between it and the app gets bigger too).

For this reason, I'd like to know if there is a way to make that space between the status bar and the apps disappear but still maintain the overscan function. I've seen that I could resize the phone with the "size" command, but it also shortens the bottom part, which doesn't need to be shorten since it works perfectly. It only is an esthetic problem because the overscan function works perfectly, but I still would like to fix it. Thank you!

This would be the 20 overscan [image: 20 overscan]

And this would be the 50 overscan [image: 50 overscan]

Comment: Please mention Android version in your question// overscan is depreciated but [other solutions may work](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232942/131553)