# 'adb wm size' to part of the screen

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop, accessibility, screen-resolution, flyme-os

I want my android version 5.1 screen to be more accessible

The base resolution of my android screen is
720x1280

I did

> adb shell wm size 720x892

and it gave me this:

[image]

Now I want to achieve this:

[image]

How do I do that?
Tried wm overscan, but it only moves the edges and you can't actualy control the screen position

Comment: [Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230374/131553) // As you can see there Android version matters. Please [edit] your question and tags to mention Android version. Adding device details may also help