# How To Add A Custom Border Which is unable to be touch Android

Tags: screen

[image: Phone]

As an example the phone above contains border really close to the edge which is one the same as my current phone, playing games sometimes causes accidental touch from the side which will block touches, Example: PubgMobile

I'm wondering is there a way to add a custom border (black bar preferably) which blocks touches and fixes screen resolution as the camera blocks the game instead of going around

Extra :
Wondering if theres a way to lock rotation on horizontal on certain position ie not moving up or down

Comment: Please check out this question and answers: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/resize-screen-for-dead-touch-zone