# Offset screen to non-broken area

Tags: adb, shell, android-tv

My android tv is broken and about half the display is invisible.

I followed this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113782/5156) and tried to offset the display using

```
adb shell wm overscan 960,540,0,0
```

This is supposed to move display to bottom left side of screen. But this only works on screen saver and app launcher screen. Youtube and other apps still open full screen.

How do I offset all apps and everything?